# How to find unnecessary loaded modules in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.4, magento

I'm trying to find out which Apache modules I really need to run Magento.
Is there a easy way to find out which modules I need, of all these loaded modules?

The server is using the following modules (as far as I know):

```
rewrites
deflate
log
header
ssl
auth
vhost
expires
mime
dir
alias
```

Right now we have all these loaded:

```
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 buffer_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 ext_filter_module (shared)
 request_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 substitute_module (shared)
 sed_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 mime_magic_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 unique_id_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 session_module (shared)
 session_cookie_module (shared)
 session_crypto_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 unixd_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 info_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 vhost_alias_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
```

Comment: the best and only apache module i know is - NGINX :)

Comment: Yeah so they told me, but that's not possible at the moment :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using mod_info to see the complete Apache configuration on one page.  Then scroll down the server-info page and you'll start seeing directives grouped by module name.  If a module doesn't have anything in its "Current Configuration" section, I'm pretty sure that means you aren't using it.

Take note however that there's a possibility of an .htaccess file in some directory on the site using a module without it being listed in here, so look through those files as well.